# MySQL - 3 tables, is this complex join even possible?

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables: users, groups and relation.

- Table users with fields: usrID, usrName, usrPass, usrPts
- Table groups with fields: grpID, grpName, grpMinPts
- Table relation with fields: uID, gID

User can be placed in group in two ways:

- if collect group minimal number of points (users.usrPts > group.grpMinPts ORDER BY group.grpMinPts DSC LIMIT 1)
- if his relation to the group is manually added in relation tables (user ID provided as uID, as well as group ID provided as gID in table named relation)

Can I create **one single** query, to determine for every user (or one specific), which group he belongs, but, manual relation (using relation table) should have higher priority than usrPts compared to grpMinPts? Also, I do not want to have one user shown twice (to show his real group by points, but related group also)...

Thanks in advance! :) I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN (relation LEFT JOIN groups ON (relation.gID = groups.grpID) ON users.usrID = relation.uID
```

Using this I managed to extract specified relations (from relation table), but, I have no idea how to include user points, respecting above mentioned priority (specified first). I know how to do this in a few separated queries in php, that is simple, but I am curious, can it be done using one single query?

EDIT TO ADD:

Thanks to really educational technique using [coalesce](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php) @GordonLinoff provided, I managed to make this query to work as I expected. So, here it goes:

```
SELECT o.usrID, o.usrName, o.usrPass, o.usrPts, t.grpID, t.grpName
FROM (
    SELECT u.*, COALESCE(relationgroupid,groupid) AS thegroupid
        FROM (
        SELECT u.*, (
            SELECT grpID
            FROM groups g
            WHERE u.usrPts > g.grpMinPts
            ORDER BY g.grpMinPts DESC 
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS groupid, (
            SELECT grpUID
            FROM relation r
            WHERE r.userUID = u.usrID
        ) AS relationgroupid
        FROM users u
    )u
)o
JOIN groups t ON t.grpID = o.thegroupid
```

Also, if you are wondering, like I did, is this approach faster or slower than doing three queries and processing in php, the answer is that this is slightly faster way. Average time of this query execution and showing results on a webpage is 14 ms. Three simple queries, processing in php and showing results on a webpage took 21 ms. Average is based on 10 cases, average execution time was, really, a constant time.

Comment: +1 For explaining/trying and hopefully learning from a good answer! :)

Comment: Of course, every correct answer is a lesson, more or less good lesson. It is important that answer stimulates me to think, like Gordon Linoff's do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach that uses correlated subqueries to get each of the values.  It then chooses the appropriate one using the precedence rule that if the `relations` exist use that one, otherwise use the one from the groups table:

```
select u.*,
       coalesce(relationgroupid, groupid) as thegroupid
from (select u.*,
             (select grpid from groups g where u.usrPts > g.grpMinPts order by g.grpMinPts desc limit 1
             ) as groupid,
             (select gid from relations r where r.userId = u.userId
             ) as relationgroupid
      from users u
    ) u
```

Comment: I AM AMAZED! :) Really! :) It is working perfect. But one more question, from aspect of speed of execution... This one query, ore more queries and processing in php? :)

Comment: @DekiB . . . I believe the performance will be pretty similar doing this as one query versus three.  In all cases, you can improve the performance by having an index on `groups(grpMinPts)` and `relations(userId)`.

Comment: I already have indexes there, so it's OK. I thing I did good job when it comes to database design (not the best, but I am still learning) Your post was really educational. Comments are too short so I will edit my question, just to show how I managed to do exactly what I wanted to, using your technique and, I will kindly ask you to look at it, and verify if I am doing it right way.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
select user.name, group.name
from group
join relation on relation.gid = group.gid
join user on user.uid = relation.uid
union
select user.name, g1.name
from group g1
join group g2 on g2.minpts > g1.minpts
join user on user.pts between g1.minpts and g2.minpts
```